# Loading from file to linked list

Tags: c, data-structures

I am trying to load an unknown amount of data from a file in to a linked list

**Load Function**

```
void load(FILE *file, Node **head) // while feof somewhere
{
    char tempArtist[30]={'\0'}, tempAlbum[30]={'\0'}, tempTitle[30]={'\0'}, tempGenre[30]={'\0'},tempSpace='\0';
    char tempPlay[100]={'\0'}, tempRating[6]={'\0'}, tempMins[8]={'\0'}, tempSecs[8]={'\0'};

    Data *temp;

    temp=(Data*)malloc(sizeof(Data));

            while(!feof(file))
            {
            fscanf(file,"%s",tempArtist);
            fscanf(file,"%s",tempAlbum);
            fscanf(file,"%s",tempTitle);
            fscanf(file,"%s",tempGenre);
            fscanf(file,"%s",tempMins);
            fscanf(file,"%s",tempSecs);
            fscanf(file,"%s",tempPlay);
            fscanf(file,"%s",tempRating);

            temp->mins=strdup(tempMins);
            temp->secs=strdup(tempSecs);
            temp->album=strdup(tempAlbum);
            temp->artist=strdup(tempArtist);
            temp->genre=strdup(tempGenre);
            temp->song=strdup(tempTitle);
            temp->played=strdup(tempPlay);
            temp->rating=strdup(tempRating);    

            insertFront(head,temp);

            }

}
```

The problem I am having is that when I go to print out the list all the entries are the same as the last one read from the file. This is something to do with the strdup() but I can't get it to copy to the data type without getting access violations.

What is another method(proper method) that I could use to copy the strings read from the file and pass them to the insert?

**InsertFront**

```
void insertFront(Node **head, Data *data)
{
    Node *temp=makeNode(data);

    if ((*head) == NULL)
    {
        *head=temp;
    }
    else
    {
        temp->pNext=*head;
        *head=temp;
    }

}
```

**Data struct**

```
typedef struct data
{
    char *artist;
    char *album;
    char *song;
    char *genre;
    char *played;
    char *rating;
    char *mins;
    char *secs;
}Data;
```

**testing file**

```
snoop
heartbeat
swiggity
rap
03
10
25
4
hoodie
cakeboy
birthday
hiphop
02
53
12
5
```

Comment: With your `struct` definition, you can't `strdup` to `temp->album`, which is an array. (In my compiler, the assignment is an error.) You could, however, `strcpy` to it. Why not make the `album` field a pointer, too, for consistency?

Comment: In this case, it might be useful to know the contents of your file. (Or an exceprt that reproduces thererror, if the file is large.)

Comment: @MOehm It was supposed to be a pointer, I was messing around to see if that might fix the issue. I'll add the file contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the same instance of `temp` for all your lines. The allocation should go inside the loop, ideally after you have established that the whole entry was read in successfully.

By the way, `feof` is [not a good way to control input loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong?lq=1). You should check the return value of `fscanf` instead.

```
while (1) {
    if (fscanf(file,"%s",tempAlbum) < 1 ) break;
    if (fscanf(file,"%s",tempArtist) < 1) break;
    // ...

    temp = (Data *) malloc(sizeof(Data));

    temp->album=strdup(tempAlbum);
    temp->artist=strdup(tempArtist);
    // ...

    insertFront(head, temp);
}
```

Note how the allocation of a new node happens only after a whole record was read.

There are other ways to improve the code. For example you have very short buffers for the strings that contain numerical data. What if there is a line slip-up and you read a longer line into into such a short buffer? Also, your input seems to be line-wise, so it might be good to use `fgets` instead of `fscan(f, "%s")`, which will only read "words" and will have problems with lines that have spaces.

Comment: Thank you, moving the malloc to the inside of the loop fix my issue.

Answer (score 0):

while(!eof) is wrong. You can do like.

```
for (;;) {
    ret = fscanf()
    if(ret == EOF) break;
}
```